# NodeJS - SocketIO over SSL with websocket transport

Tags: python, node.js, ssl, websocket, socket.io

I have a NodeJS-socketIO server that has clients listening from JS, PHP & Python. It works like a charm when the communication happens over plain HTTP/WS channel.

Now, when i try to secure this communication, the websocket transport is not working anymore. It falls back to xhr-polling(long polling) transport. Xhr-polling still works for JS client but not on python which purely depends on socket transport.

Things i tried:

1. On node, Using **https**(with commercial certificates) instead of http - Works good for serving pages via Node but not for socketIO
2. Proxy via **HAProxy (1.15-dev19)**. From HTTPS(HAProxy) to HTTP(Node). Couldn't get Websocket transport working and it **falls back to xhr-polling** on JS. **Python gets *502* on handshake**.
3. Proxy via **STunnel** (for HTTPS) -> HAProxy(Websocket Proxy) -> Node(SocketIO) - This doesnt work either. Python client still gets 502 on handshake.
4. Proxy via Stunnel(HTTPS) -> Node(SocketIO) - This doesnt work too. Not sure if STunnel support websocket proxy
5. **node-http-proxy** : Throws 500(***An error has occurred: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}***) on websocket and falls back to xhr-polling

Im sure its a common use case and there is a solution exist. Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We are trying to connect a node.js server with socket.io, from a python client using socketIO-client, with no success. Can you share some code snippets from the connection?

Comment: If you are using SocketIO 1.x, the python client wont work. Try to use SocketIO 0.9 with the python client and let me know if it still doesnt work. The author of python client socketIO-client is working on the update to match it with the 1.x version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My case seems to be a rare one. I built this whole environment on a EC2 instance based on Amazon Linux. As almost all the yum packages are not up to date, i had to install pretty much every yum packages from source. By doing so i could have missed configuration unchanged/added. Or HAProxy required lib could have been not the latest.

In any case, i tried building the environment again on ubuntu 12.04 based EC2 instance. HAProxy worked like a charm with a bit of configuration tweaks. I can now connect my SocketIO server from JS, Python & PHP over SSL without any problem. I could also create a Secured TCP Amazon ELB that listens on 443 and proxy it to non-standard port (8xxx).

Let me know if anyone else encounters a similar problem, I will be happy to help!

Comment: Can you please share your HAProxy config ? also are you using nginx on top of HA Proxy ? If yes , how are securing the traffic to nginx .

Comment: @RanaDeep Sorry for such a late reply. No, Im not using Nginx with HAProxy. If you still need the config [HAProxy config](https://gist.github.com/karthikj/8193588)