# SocketStream demo app modified to HTTPS fails connection

Tags: https, socketstream

Using version 3.5.

The demo app works great with the default HTTP settings.  I followed the HTTPS usage suggestions on their slideshow tour and it worked -- or seemed to.  The page is served correctly, but chat messages do not post.  Open up the console and get these messages repeated every few seconds up to countout:

```
Connection down :-( entry.coffee?ts=1377958052923&pathPrefix=app:9
GET https://localhost/engine.io/default/?uid=87789528630674353598151356&transport=polling  system?ts=1377958052923:2337
Request.create system?ts=1377958052923:2337
Request system?ts=1377958052923:2269
XHR.request system?ts=1377958052923:2216
XHR.doPoll system?ts=1377958052923:2245
Polling.poll system?ts=1377958052923:2527
Polling.doOpen system?ts=1377958052923:2471
(anonymous function)
```

`entry.coffee` has nothing in it but logging functions.  That's where the "`Connection down :-(`" is found, triggered by `ss.server.on disconnect`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745249/html5-websocket-with-ssl

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122835/nodejs-socketio-over-ssl-with-websocket-transport?rq=1

Comment: https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream/issues/252

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gotcha here is that if you're running a HTTPS server, then you'll need to listen on port 443.